# Filter Data Frame by Matching Multiple String in Multiple Columns

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have been unsuccessfully trying to filter my data frame using the `dplyr` and `grep` libraries using a list of string across multiple columns of my data frame. I would assume this is a simple task, but either nobody has asked my specific question or it's not as easy as I thought it would originally be.

For the following data frame...

```
foo <- data.frame(var.1 = c('a', 'b',' c'),
           var.2 = c('b', 'd', 'e'),
           var.3 = c('c', 'f', 'g'),
           var.4 = c('z', 'a', 'b'))
```

... I would like to be able to filter row wise to find rows that contain all three variables a, b, and c in them. **My sought after answer would only return row 1, as it contains a, b, and c, and not return rows 2 and 3 even though they contain two of the three sought after variables, they do not contain all three in the same row.**

I'm running into issues where `grep` only allows specifying vectors or one column at a time when I really just care about finding string across many columns in the same row.

I've also used `dplyr` to `filter` using `%in%`, but it just returns when any of the variables are present:

```
foo %>% 
  filter(var.1 %in% c('a', 'b', 'c') |
           var.2 %in% c('a', 'b', 'c') |
           var.3 %in% c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

Thanks for any and all help and please, let me know if you need any clarification!

Comment: `foo[apply(foo, 1, function(x) all(c('a', 'b', 'c') %in% x)), ]`

Comment: `apply( foo, 2, function(x) all( grepl(x = x, pattern = "[abc]" ) ))`

Comment: `apply( foo, 2, function(x) sum( grepl(x = x, pattern = "[abc]" ) ) == 3)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach in base R where we check if the elements of `foo` are equal to `"a"`, `"b"`, or `"c"` successively, add the Booleans and check if the sum of those Booleans for each row is greater than or equal to 3

```
Reduce("+", lapply(c("a", "b", "c"), function(x) rowSums(foo == x) > 0)) >=3
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

**Timings**

```
foo = matrix(sample(letters[1:26], 1e7, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5)
system.time(Reduce("+", lapply(letters[1:20], function(x) rowSums(foo == x) > 0)) >=20)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   3.26    0.48    3.79 

system.time(apply(foo, 1, function(x) all(letters[1:20] %in% x)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  18.86    0.00   19.19 


identical(Reduce("+", lapply(letters[1:20], function(x) rowSums(foo == x) > 0)) >=20, 
          apply(foo, 1, function(x) all(letters[1:20] %in% x)))
#[1] TRUE
>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem arises from trying to apply "tidyverse" solutions to data that isn't tidy. Here's the tidy solution, which uses `melt` to make your data tidy. See how much tidier this solution is?

```
> library(reshape2)
> rows = foo %>%
      mutate(id=1:nrow(foo)) %>% 
      melt(id="id") %>% 
      filter(value=="a" | value=="b" | value=="c") %>%
      group_by(id) %>% 
      summarize(N=n()) %>% 
      filter(N==3) %>%
      select(id) %>%
      unlist
Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped
```

That gives you a vector of matching row indexes, which you can then subset your original data frame with:

```
> foo[rows,]
  var.1 var.2 var.3 var.4
1     a     b     c     z
>
```

Comment: `value=="a" | value=="b" | value=="c"` could be `value %in% c("a","b","c")` surely.